# Javascript encodeURIComponent and Java decode issue

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, uriencoding

I have a certain text I am encoding in JS using encodeURIComponent. The original text is

```
weoowuyteeeee !_.

Test could you please resubmit again?
```

I am doing the following in my JS code before sending it.

```
var text = encodeURIComponent($("#txt11").val());
```

Should I not be doing that?

Once I encode it using encodeURIComponent, it becomes

---

weoowuyteeeee%2520!_.%252C%250A%250ATest%252C%2520%2520could%2520you%2520please%2520resubmit%2520again%253F

---

I'm trying to decrypt the same on the Java side using

```
String decodedString1 = URLDecoder.decode(myObject.getText(), "UTF-8");
```

but I see this as the output, not the original text. What am I doing wrong?

---

weoowuyteeeee%20!_.%2C%0A%0ATest%2C%20%20could%20you%20please%20resubmit%20again%3F

---

Comment: You're double-encoding it.  Don't do that.

Comment: Updated the post. I am manually doing a encodeURIComponent. Should I not be doing that?

Comment: That completely depends on how your value is flowing.  But it is somehow being encoded twice

Answer (score 3):

You are encoding your data twice.

Initially, you have encoded your data and later it is encoded again.

Eg: Let your text be

> Hello World

After encoding it becomes

> Hello%20World

If you encode again it becomes

> Hello%2520World

Reason

> % from %20 is encoded to %25. So the space becomes %2520.

Normal AJAX can will automatically encode your data before sending to the server side. Check where the 2nd encoding is happening.

Comment: Updated the post. I am manually doing a encodeURIComponent. Should I not be doing that?

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem like i'm double encoding. I am only encoding once in JS and decoding in Java.

Comment: You can clearly see that the data encoded is double encoded